# unserializing multiple attachments data

Tags: php, upload, phpmyadmin

I have stored  some multiple attachments in my database, in one column by serializing the Attachments data through code:

```
        $files = array(
'file1' => base64_encode(file_get_contents('back.jpg')),
'file2' => base64_encode(file_get_contents('email.jpg')),
'file3' => base64_encode(file_get_contents('web.jpg')),
  );
     // serialize
     $filesData = serialize($files);
```

Now, in another php page, i am getting the files to download , in that i m UNserializing the above files data, getting them from the database column "Data"

Using the following code to unserialize data, but it seems that the data is not unserailized, I have saved three pics, and when i retrive them, i get a .txt file downloaded, in which written there "Array"

```
     if($result->num_rows == 1) {
         $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
       // Print headers
            header("Content-Type: ". $row['mime']);
            header("Content-Length: ". $row['size']);
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $row['name']);

        $files = unserialize($row['data']);
            echo $files;
        }
```

Comment: One filename and content-disposition, but the data of three files. How should that work? I thjink you need to re-read the HTTP specification(s) if there is something that allows you to send three files at once with one HTTP response (I don't think it's easily possible, and otherwise not trivial to solve as it's a very uncommon scenario but there are multipart responses in HTTP and some browsers might even support it).

Answer (score 0):

$files is an array containing the three files, what do you expect?

"Array" is the result of the string cast from echo.

try echo $files['file1']  etc..

Comment: I have tried echo $files['file1']  , same result only the .txt file now contains the "code characters for images" i think.

Comment: i cant figure out what you're trying to do please specify further